# Compare and merge 2 MS Word documents with Java and OpenOffice API?

Tags: api, merge, ms-word, compare, openoffice.org

How do I compare and merge 2 MS Word documents with Java and the [OpenOffice API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Network_Objects)?

I just want to conform that is it possible to compare 2 MS Word documents with the OpenOffice API.

Comment: If you want clarification it's best to update your first question or leave a comment against one of the answers, rather than re-ask an almost identical question.  If you leave comments on your first question people will be notified and are more likely to reply.

Comment: thanks will do it next time ...